# SAX parser raise some error

Tags: java, android

I got some issue with parsing, when I PHP based web service. I got stuck still from 2 day. I can't get any output in Activity. When I print it in Handler I got successfully print variable.
here are some logcate:

```
02-08 00:51:04.889: WARN/System.err(606): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 805: not well-formed (invalid token)
02-08 00:51:04.893: WARN/System.err(606):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:523)
02-08 00:51:04.893: WARN/System.err(606):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:482)
02-08 00:51:04.893: WARN/System.err(606):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:320)
02-08 00:51:04.893: WARN/System.err(606):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:277)
02-08 00:51:04.893: WARN/System.err(606):     at com.ESM.viewAllpartActivity.onCreate(viewAllpartActivity.java:69)
02-08 00:51:04.893: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-08 00:51:04.904: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-08 00:51:04.904: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-08 00:51:04.904: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-08 00:51:04.904: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-08 00:51:04.904: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-08 00:51:04.914: WARN/System.err(606):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when I have call xml parsing.

**here I have Past Code::-**

```
package com.awe;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class viewAllpartActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    /* declare widgets */

    String nickname;
    String type;
    boolean flag = true;
    ListView lview3;

    blog_list_adapter adapter;

    String[] str_blogImage;
    String[] str_blogtitle;
    String[] str_morelink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_allparty);

        Button home_logout;
        final Intent homeintent;
        homeintent = new Intent(viewAllpartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        home_logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vap_logout);
        home_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(homeintent);
                finish();

            }
        });
        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                    "URL?api=ViewBooking_Admin");

            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            viewAllPartyHandler myXMLHandler = new viewAllPartyHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

            viewAllPartydataset parsedLoginDataSet = myXMLHandler
                    .getParsedRegistrationData();
            ArrayList<String> Bookingid = myXMLHandler.getbooking_id();
            ArrayList<String> partyname = myXMLHandler.br3;
            System.out.println("partyname :::: : "+partyname);
            new xyz().execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                viewAllpartActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            this.dialog.show();
            this.dialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            // put your code which preload with processDialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // put your code here
            try {
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
                URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                        "url?api=ViewBooking_Admin");

                /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
                viewAllPartyHandler myXMLHandler = new viewAllPartyHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

                viewAllPartydataset parsedLoginDataSet = myXMLHandler
                        .getParsedRegistrationData();
                ArrayList<String> Bookingid = myXMLHandler.getbooking_id();
                ArrayList<String> partyname = myXMLHandler.br3;
                System.out.println("partyname :::: : "+partyname);
                /*str_blogImage = Bookingid.toArray(new String[Bookingid.size()]);
                str_morelink = partyname.toArray(new String[partyname.size()]);*/
                System.out.println("partyname :::: : "+partyname);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

            lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vap_listview);
            /*lview3.setAdapter(new
                    ArrayAdapter<String>(viewAllpartActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,
                            str_morelink));*/

            lview3.setOnItemClickListener(viewAllpartActivity.this);

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        System.out.println("str_morelink ::: " + arg2);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("url", str_morelink[arg2]);
        Intent i1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), blogwebview.class);
        i1.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i1);
        // finish();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent homeback;

            homeback = new Intent(viewAllpartActivity.this, home.class);
            startActivity(homeback);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your xml is not well formatted (might have special characters). I would sugggest log the xml and make sure you are getting correct xml.

Comment: Could you show the XML you're trying to parse?

Comment: If your xml is well formed, I'd have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827006/sax-expatparserparseexception .

Comment: @javanna Please check out i have update my xml here: http://pastebin.com/ttVvzJqK

Comment: @Traroth http://pastebin.com/ttVvzJqK

Comment: @thinksteep http://pastebin.com/ttVvzJqK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your xml and specially wiht '&' chararcters so you could define a CDTA section to hold the value...

Comment: so how can i apply in my handler?

Comment: this post is about CDATA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: can you tell me how can i do it my side not server side?

Comment: try to replace & with &amp; when parsing

Comment: go through the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467830/xml-parsing-with-sax-how-to-handle-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example [here](http://pastebin.com/ttVvzJqK), it's not well formed. It contains not encoded '&' chararcters.

The right solution is to change the XML generating process in order to get well-formed XML files.

But you can try a workaround by replacing all "&" with "&", in your whole file, before you parse it.

Comment: so please provide me solution

Comment: You can't parse this file as it is. So the solution is to change your XML is generated. Either replace your special characters with entities or include the problematic text in a CDATA section.